# is TFX meant to be used for data preprocessing

Tags: tfx

I would like to get some input on how TFX is to be used if my approach was correct.
My end goal was to do some predictions on a raw stream of series data which required some preprocessing.

Normally we have flink jobs running basic analysis such as windowing, grouping and computing statistics.
However the thought was to move these pipelines over to beam and have TFX use these beam components to do further computing.

This proved to be quite challenging as TFX components have a strict API and expect all intermediary data to be TFRecords.

So my question is, is TFX aiming to handle all preprocessing logic (grouping, windowing.. etc..) or is it more for data engineering?

Answer (score 0):

TFX is meant to handle all the Preprocessing Logic. Your requirement can be fulfilled by the in built functions of Tensorflow Transform. Some of them are shown below:

```
tft.bucketize, tft.compute_and_apply_vocabulary, tft.pca, tft.scale_to_z_score, etc..
```

Yes, TFX components (especially TF Transform) expects all intermediary data to be `TF.Example` format. And there are easy ways to convert our Dataset to that Format.

Code for converting CSV Data to `TF.Example` is shown below:

```
from tfx.utils.dsl_utils import csv_input
from tfx.components.example_gen.csv_example_gen.component import CsvExampleGen

examples = csv_input(os.path.join(base_dir, 'data/simple'))
example_gen = CsvExampleGen(input_base=examples)
```

Other way to convert the Data which can be accepted by TF Transform is:

```
converter = tft.coders.CsvCoder(ordered_columns, RAW_DATA_METADATA.schema)
```

For more information, refer the links,

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/examplegen and

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/transform/census#transform_the_data